# Laravel 9 enum conditional if

Tags: laravel, collections, enums

I'm create one enum, and I added one condition:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Enums;

use App\Models\collections;

enum ServiceColections : string {


    case POS = (isset(collections::first()))? 'POS' : '';

}
```

the condition is the following if there are items in the database(table collections), so create case POS, but if they don't exist don't create.

currently I'm having this error: `Enum case value must be compile-time evaluatable`

why it dont work?

Comment: That is not possible. Errors says it clearly. `Enum case value must be compile-time evaluatable` - means that the case value must be available at compile-time it cannot be inferred during compile-time.

Comment: better way is added conditional in view?

Comment: Need more context about what is the use case and what you want to use the Enum for.

Comment: I don't know what a better way is but you can't use an enum in this way. Use something else. A helper function, a configuration variable defined at runtime, literally there's a lot of ways you CAN do this with, but an enum is not one of those ways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error its self say, this will not work at the time of compiling.

What we can do is, add enum method:

```
use App\Models\collections;

enum ServiceColections 
{
    case POS;

    public function collection(): string // name the function of your choice
    {
        return match($this) 
        {
            self::POS => collections::first() ? 'POS' : '',
        };
    }
}
```

Methods can be used like so:

```
\App\Enums\ServiceColections::POS->collection();
```